# Converting a line of Java to C#

Tags: c#, java

Can someone explain to me what this line below in Java means and how would I convert it to C#? Thanks.

```
private class X extends Y<Void, Object, Void> {
.......
}
```

Comment: Looks like Generics but I've never used it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can use `java.lang.Void` as a type argument when you really don't care about that type parameter, and it will always be `null`. For example:

```
public interface Command<T> {
  T execute();
}

public class VoidReturningCommand implements Command<Void> {
  public Void execute() {
    // executes ....
    return null; // don't care about the return...
  }
}
```

In C#, `System.Void` *cannot* be used like that.

So, to communicate that the object is really *void*, you can create an uninstantiatable type for it:

```
public sealed class Nothingness {
  private Nothingness() { }
}
```

And then use it:

```
private class X : Y<Nothingness, object, Nothingness> {

}
```

`null` is the only valid value for class `Nothingness`.

(Other names that I thought for class `Nothingness` include `Null`, `Nothing` - bad for VB.NET -, `Void`, `Unit`, `Ignored`, [`Mu`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29) - you decide which one is best for you)

This carries the *intent* of the original Java code to C#.

Answer (score 4):

The class X [inherits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29) from the [generic class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) Y. The Y class has three generic parameters. X extends of class Y with parameters `Void`, `Object` and `Void`.

In C# this would look as follows:

```
private class X : Y<object, object, object> {
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, void can't be passed as a type, so you have to pass at least `object` in C#.

---

This code does look fishy. Class Y needs to be aware of three types, of which two you [never want to assign a non-null value to](http://www.jroller.com/tackline/entry/void_references) (the void types).

Comment: void isn't a type or an alias to one in C# it's just a keyword, your code won't work with "Keyword 'void' cannot be used in this context".

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox, `void` *is* a type, or rather an alias to the struct `System.Void`. But you are correct that you cannot use it here.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram : Well actually... void isn't a type in the C# language or an alias to anything. System.Void denote an empty return type at the IL level and could be seen when dealing with reflection. See for example the part of the specification that is special casing typeof(void) never specifying that the result have anything to do with System.Void. In the current microsoft compiler it's obvious that void isn't special cased in most cases and just an alias to System.Void but it isn't specified anywhere in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Steven's answer doesn't look quite right - `void` can't be used this way in C#.

Instead you could represent what is `void` in the Java implementation as an `Action` or maybe `Func` in .NET, as such (omitting any complexities such as constraints):

```
private class Y<T, K, Z> { }

private class X : Y<Action, object, Action>
{

}
```

What's happening here is that we're defining `X`, which is a class in its own right, to *inherit* the class `Y`. `Y` is in fact a *generic* type (of which the utilisation kind of reduces the need and even desire to use `object` here) and so also exposes parameters within the angle brackets - this means, for instance, that `object` could be changed to `Fruit` and you could instantiate `Y` with any sub-classing type, such as `Apple`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for information on inheritance, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) for information on generics.

This whole implementation is kind of backwards, though, unless `X` is attempting to hide information about the underlying type and its arguments with intent.

A slightly more elaborate example just to illustrate how one might use generics and inheritance may look a little like this:

```
    public abstract class Fruit { }

    public class Apple : Fruit { }

    public class Pear : Fruit { }

    public class LunchBox<A>
        where A : Fruit
    {
        public A FruitSnack { get; set; }
    }

    public class LunchBox<A, B> : LunchBox<A>
        where A : Fruit 
        where B : Fruit
    {
        public B ExtraFruitSnack { get; set; }
    }

    var myLunchBox = new LunchBox<Apple>();

    var myBiggerLunchBox = new LunchBox<Apple, Pear>();
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll stick to object instead of Action, since I prefer to think I've a null object than a null delegate.

Comment: @Matías: However, `object` can't _do_ anything, an `Action` can.

Comment: Anyway, I believe this question is someway useless and C# approaches would end in another, different solution than Java and "Void" one.

Comment: Thanks, I like the option of using Action although object works as well.

Answer (score 0):

This means that it is adding functionality onto Class `Y` which takes some generic object types to instantiate.

In C# this would look like

```
private class X : Y<null, Object, null>
{

}
```

This is called `inheritance` where `X` is inheriting the attributes of the Base Class `Y`.

I don't think however that you can pass in a `null` like that.

Comment: The original code snipped uses `void`, which obviously won't work in C#. But neither will `null`.

Comment: @Anyhony Pegram, yea I'm trying to think of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Means that a private class X inherits Y class, and Y has 3 generic parameters: Void, Object and Void.

In C# you can't use "void" as a generic type parameter, so it would look like this:

```
private class X : Y<object, object, object>
{
}
```

And members that would return void now return a null object. And that's all.